# Can we use regular glasses with inlaid display to display images to a wearer?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

`Object (virtual) (distance: d)   <--->    Glass with some display + Human Eye`

Would it be possible to display something onto a regular glass covered with a display (preferably transparent) to give the viewer the illusion that there is an object at distance `d`? An example would be Augmented Reality glasses but rather than using a projector or HUD display, using the surface of regular glasses instead.

Comment: It's tricky trying to focus on stuff that close to the eye, unless you have fairly extreme myopia.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but can't we 'transform' what is being displayed at the glass surface level to mimic something actually located at a distance? As in the pixels at the glass surface level serve as the 'source' that can give the illusion of a virtual image at distance d.

Comment: I don't think so. But you should [edit] that info into your question, since that's the central issue of whether your idea would or wouldn't work.